# CreateHwndRenderTarget throwing exception: read access violation. **this** was nullptr

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, direct2d

I have been recently been learning Win32 API using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-direct2d-program) tutorial. I have been trying to create a window which displays a circle using Direct2D based on it. However, the program keeps throwing an exception:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
**this** was nullptr.
```

VS 2019 then opens d2d1.h to this section:

```cpp
CreateHwndRenderTarget(
        CONST D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES &renderTargetProperties,
        CONST D2D1_HWND_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES &hwndRenderTargetProperties,
        _COM_Outptr_ ID2D1HwndRenderTarget **hwndRenderTarget 
        )  
    {
        return CreateHwndRenderTarget(&renderTargetProperties, &hwndRenderTargetProperties, hwndRenderTarget);
    }
```

This is the section of my code which causes this:

```cpp
HRESULT CreateGraphicsResources(HWND hWnd) {
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    if (pRenderTarget == NULL) {
        RECT rc;
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);

        D2D1_SIZE_U size = D2D1::SizeU(rc.right, rc.bottom);

        hr = pFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(
            D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(),
            D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(hWnd, size),
            &pRenderTarget);
        
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
            const D2D1_COLOR_F color = D2D1::ColorF(1.0f, 1.0f, 0);
            hr = pRenderTarget->CreateSolidColorBrush(color, &pBrush);

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                CalculateLayout();
            }
        }
    }
    return hr;
}
```

This is where I call the function:

```cpp
case WM_PAINT:
        {
            HRESULT hr = CreateGraphicsResources(hWnd);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                PAINTSTRUCT ps;
                BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

                pRenderTarget->BeginDraw();

                pRenderTarget->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::SkyBlue));
                pRenderTarget->FillEllipse(ellipse, pBrush);

                hr = pRenderTarget->EndDraw();
                if (FAILED(hr) || hr == D2DERR_RECREATE_TARGET)
                {
                    DiscardGraphicsResources();
                }
                EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            }
}
```

So, what does this exception mean, and what is causing it to be thrown?
Also, how can I fix it?
Thank you for your help.
The full file is available [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1AzRwOemy26K7-A6L19wAciaeop2JXeGq?usp=sharing) .

Comment: We do not need the full code. The shown code is not enough. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Well, it says. "this" was nullptr. "this" means the object you called the function on. So in `pFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(...)` it's pFactory. So why is pFactory null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pFactory reference is null. But you do initialize it, so why is it null? Because your code is broken, it does this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    ... some code
    case WM_SIZE:
        {
           ... some code
        }
        
    // there is no break here!
    // first call to WM_SIZE falls down to WM_DESTROY which destroys your pFactory...
    
    case WM_DESTROY:
        DiscardGraphicsResources();
        SafeRelease(&pFactory);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
```

Just add a `break` before `WM_DESTROY`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I totally missed that! I though something had gone way over my head that was awfully important, but it turned out that I missed an awfully important `break;`.

Comment: Happens to everyone. Sometimes, only a new eye can spot the bug. That's why giving full repro code is so important :-)